# I need help about getting list of days from a week number with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date, time, strtotime

I want to create a function to get a list of days from a week number and a year as parameters.

I've tried to write this following function, which only works when my week number is greater than 10.

```php
public function getDaysofWeek(int $year, int $week){
        // ...
        $days = array();
        for($d=1; $d<8; $d++) {
            $days[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year."W". $week .$d));
        }
        var_dump($days);
        // ...
```

For the week 37 of 2019 (week of today), i got this (actually the correct result) :

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "09/09/2019" 
[1]=> string(10) "10/09/2019" 
[2]=> string(10) "11/09/2019" 
[3]=> string(10) "12/09/2019" 
[4]=> string(10) "13/09/2019" 
[5]=> string(10) "14/09/2019" 
[6]=> string(10) "15/09/2019" }
```

But when my week number is less than 10, i got this (here, week 05 of 2019):

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(10) "16/12/2019" 
[1]=> string(10) "23/12/2019" 
[2]=> string(10) "30/12/2019" 
[3]=> string(10) "01/01/1970" 
[4]=> string(10) "01/01/1970" 
[5]=> string(10) "01/01/1970" 
[6]=> string(10) "01/01/1970" }
```

I can't understand why this problem is happening, does someone have an 
explanation or solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that as you are using an integer for the week, when you build this into the date in

```
$days[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year."W". $week .$d));
```

You end up with an error as the date isn't formed correctly (`2019W5`), you need to make sure you have a 2 digit week.

This just formats the week to ensure it comes out as `2019W05`...

```
$days[] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year."W". 
       sprintf("%02d", $week) .$d));
```